# Drupal integration with PandoDoc or DocSign

Tags: drupal, integration, digital-signature, pandadoc

What is the best practice for the integration of the two platforms for Drupal as, in addition to electronic signing, the client will require the signed documents to be stored in Drupal as well?

I was thinking of using PandaDoc forms integration and additional requests to pull the files into Drupal afterwards?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.